Fantasy book series about a lord (and maybe a lady) who rules over a world where it's eternally spring, summer, fall, etc
I am trying to recall a series of books I think I read in the 90s--fantasy novels about a lord (and maybe a lady) who rules over a world where it's eternally spring, summer, fall, etc.  I believe there's a murder that draws all the lords together.
Can anyone give me the titles and author?

If it is eternally spring, how is it also eternally summer, etc.?

@Lexible - I'm guessing he means one lord or lady rules over a land that is eternally spring, another where it is eternally summer, etc.  I'm guessing that because of the "all the lords" mentioned in the next sentence.  But the OP will need to confirm this....

+1 @Basya Thank you! Dave editing to make that (or whatever the intention is) explicit would help clarify the question. :)

Dennis L. McKiernan's Once Upon A... series?
The books in the series are:

Once Upon a Winter's Night
Once Upon a Summer Day
Once Upon an Autumn Eve
Once Upon a Spring Morn
Once Upon a Dreadful Time

The series of books is about the lords of the four lands, each of which is ruled by a single ruler:  Borel (winter), Celeste (spring), Alain (summer), Liaze (autumn).  The viewpoint character in (at least) the first book is Camille, a mortal woman who is taken to be wife of Prince Alain.
In the final book the lord are uniting to battle a particular threat - there are definitely many deaths, but whether a singular murder is the trigger I admit I cannot recall.

Could this be A Court of Thorns and Roses (2015) by Sarah J. Maas?

When nineteen-year-old huntress Feyre kills a wolf in the woods, a terrifying creature arrives to demand retribution. Dragged to a treacherous magical land she knows about only from legends, Feyre discovers that her captor is not truly a beast, but one of the lethal, immortal faeries who once ruled her world.

The setting is a world with multiple lordships, each themed after a season. The books follow on from a murder that draws all the lords together for the first time in an age.

Spring Court: ruled by Tamlin and has a blooming rose as its symbol.
Summer Court ruled by Tarquin and has an ocean wave as its symbol.
Autumn Court ruled by Beron and has fall leaves as its symbol.
Winter Court, ruled by Kallias, has ice shards in the shape of a wolf as its symbol.


The dates don't match though. The OP's book was read in the 1990s.

@JohnRennie - I noticed that. I'm wondering if they're conflating two books.

Brian Aldiss -- Helliconia
The Helliconia trilogy is a series of science fiction books by British writer Brian W. Aldiss, set on the Earth-like planet Helliconia. It is an epic chronicling the rise and fall of a civilisation over more than a thousand years as the planet progresses through its incredibly long seasons, which last for centuries.

Looks like you've copied and pasted text from the Wikipedia page here. When doing that, it's best practice to make it clear that you're quoting from another source and provide the relevant link.
